# My @media isn't working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've gone through previous posts talking about why their media query isn't working, but it seems they are not relevant to my problem. So I'm here to seek help.

Hi guys,

Super newbie here, I've been haunting by this problem for over a week now, and I hope I can get some help here... Here's my code. I don't know the proper way to ask a question, so if there's anything to improve, let me know.

The point of the code is to make a layout that is responsive to the different width of the browser.

/*** HTML ***/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

<h1>HEADER YES PRAISE THE lORD</h1>

<div class="div-1">

\<h2\>Chicken\</h2\>

\<p\>The chicken is a type of domesticated fowl, a subspecies of the red junglefowl. It is one of the most common and widespread domestic animals, with a total population of more than 19 billion as of 2011.\</p\>
</div>

<div class="div-2">

\<h2 style="background\-color:blue;"\>Beef\</h2\>

\<p\>Beef is the culinary name for meat from cattle, particularly skeletal muscle. Humans have been eating beef since prehistoric times. Beef is a source of high\-quality protein and essential nutrients.\</p\>
</div>

<div class="div-3">

\<h2 style="background\-color:lime;"\>Sushi\</h2\>

\<p\>Sushi is a Japanese dish of specially prepared vinegared rice, usually with some sugar and salt, combined with a variety of ingredients, such as seafood, vegetables, and occasionally tropical fruits\</p\>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

/*** CSS ***/

```
{

box\-sizing: content\-box;
}

h1{

text\-align: center;
}

p{

clear:both;

padding: 10px;
}

div h2{

background\-color: red;

float: right;

border\-left: 2px solid black;

border\-bottom: 2px solid black;

text\-align: center;

padding:10px;

margin:0px;

width:100px;
}

.div-1{

box\-sizing: content\-box;

border:2px solid black;

color:white;

background\-color:grey;

margin:10px;

float:left;

}
.div-2{

box\-sizing: content\-box;

border:2px solid black;

color:white;

background\-color:grey;

margin:10px;

float:left;

}
.div-3{

box\-sizing: content\-box;

border:2px solid black;

color:white;

background\-color:grey;

margin:10px;

float:left;

}
@media(min-width: 992px;){

.div-1{

width:33&#37;;
}

.div-2{

width:33&#37;;
}

.div-3{

width:33&#37;;
}

}

@media(min-width: 768px)and(max-width:991px){

.div-1{

width:50&#37;;
}

.div-2{

width:50&#37;;
}

.div-3{

width:100&#37;;
}

}

@media(max-width: 767px){

.div-1{

width:100&#37;;
}

.div-2{

width:100&#37;;
}

.div-3{

width:100&#37;;
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you adding backslashes all around?

Comment: there is so much errors here, like what is `width: 50&#37;;`?

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px){
    //your code here
}
```

it is good to use something like

```
<div class="box first/1"></div>
<div class="box second/2"></div>
```

insted of

```
<div class="div-1"></div>
<div class="div-2"></div>
```

to avoid duplications in your css

Answer (score -1):

Two things:
Add `initial-scale=1.0` in your meta content tag.

Specify media type, in this case it is screen.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px;){

.div-1{

width:33&#37;;
}
```

Comment: You could at least try a bit harder and add correct value for width! Downvoted

Comment: Thanks man, sorry for the inconvenience. I straight up copied and pasted the code from limetext. Didn't notice the error. but thanks for giving out a solution.